# Browser form width compatibility in @media

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a form, wpcf7, and I have used the following CSS to center it, and others divs, in the middle of the page, in @media.

```
@media(min-width: 768px) 
{.wpcf7- 
form-control.wpcf7-submit {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}}
@media (min-width: 768px)  
{.contact::before, .contact::after
{display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}}@media (min-width: 768px) 
{.wpcf7{display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}} @media (min-width: 768px) 
{#anr_captcha_field_1{display: 
flex;justify-content: center; }}
```

In Apple Safari the contact form field boxes are roughly 120px too wide stretching to the right, in Chrome / Chrome, same, in Chrome / Windows works, in Explorer/ Windows works. How to fix?

The html here is massive as it included divs from several sections but here's some:

```
<label> Your Name (required)<br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input type="text" 
name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7- 
text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria- 
invalid="false" /></span> </label></p>
<p><label> Your Email (required)<br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input type="email" 
name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control 
wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates- 
as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span> 
</label></p>
<p><label> Subject<br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-subject"><input 
type="text" name="your-subject" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7- 
form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" /></span> </label></p>
<p><label> Your Message<br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message"><textarea 
name="your-message" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control 
wpcf7-textarea" aria-invalid="false"></textarea></span> </label></p>
<p><div class="anr_captcha_field"><div id="anr_captcha_field_1" 
class="anr_captcha_field_div"></div></div><span class="wpcf7-form- 
control-wrap g-recaptcha-response"></span></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control 
wpcf7-submit" /></p>
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div></form>. 
</div>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

Answer (score 0):

From the supplied code it looks like you're using the Contact Form 7 plug in. Which if you are there's a whole chunk of CSS missing that comes with the plug in, making it a tall order to answer with 100% confidence. That said, rather than using flex box to centre the form, why not try good old `margin:auto;` to sort out the alignment.

Here's an example Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/t8xLqr4y/

As we don't have the full code I've gone and added an example wrapping div element. You'll probably find you have a div with a class of .wpcf7 or .wpcf7-form-control or something like that you can use. But basically apply something like:

```
.example {
  margin: auto;
  width: 400px;
}
```

The old school `margin:auto;` does the centring for you. The width is required, but you could also use a `max-width:400px;` to make it flexible for smaller widths.

To get you input fields and textarea to behave you'll need to set them to a width of 100% and set the box-sizing to border-box.

```
.example input[type="text"], 
.example input[type="email"], 
.example textarea {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}
```

They don't need to be 100%, they can be whatever width you like, but I'm working on the assumption you want them to be the full width of the wrapping element. And of course you can use max width too if you only want them to be full width when the window narrows.

**Edit** I realise I have made no mention of media queries here. All of the above can be wrapped in a media query to your liking. Whether you do or not should not effect the approach.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I tried margin: auto and it didn't work :-(... Agreed, it seems like the perfect solution, but... That's why i went with flex.

Comment: Can I still use `.example input[type="text"], 
.example input[type="email"], 
.example textarea {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}` without `margin: auto`?

Comment: Yes. but remember that you will need to replace `.example` with whatever your wrapping element is. Most likely it would be `.wpcf7`.